# Execute stored procedure from Visual Studio 2012 Database project

Tags: visual-studio-2012, database-project

I have imported a SQL Server database into a Visual Studio 2012 database project. I am able to see the tables and stored procedures just fine. I would now like to execute stored procedures from that database within Visual Studio. Does anyone know if this is possible and if so how?

I know I could simply use Server Explorer but it would be desirable to work exclusively in the database project as that is the one synced to our version control system.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using SQL Projects, you can open the SQL Server Object Explorer within SSDT and look at the database connections for (localdb). After building your database, you should have a connection to the (localdb) server or whatever is set in your Project Debug setting.

You can also launch the Transact-SQL Editor under the SQL menu and connect to an existing database server that way. Most likely, you'll want to use your debug settings as they'd be directly connected to your project on each build.